# Merge "description" and "additional informations" product tab

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to remove the "additional information" tab, and append its content to the "description" tab. I had no problems adding new tabs or removing existing one. The problem is that, since I have to use a callback for the content of the tab, I do not know how to fetch the original content. 
My code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'exetera_custom_product_tabs', 98 );
function exetera_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {


 $tabs['description']['callback'] = function ( ) {
        $description = "Original content of the description tab here";
        $additional_information = "Original content of the Additional Information tab here";
        echo $description;
        echo $additional_information;
        };  // Custom description callback
 unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );      // Remove the additional information tab

return $tabs;
}
```

I don't know how to get the right content for the $description and $additional_information variables from the original content of the respective product tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback used to render the "Description" tab is `woocommerce_product_description_tab()`, which simply loads the template file [`single-product/tabs/description.php`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce/tags/3.5.5/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php). And for the "Additional Information" tab, the callback is `woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab()` and the template is [`single-product/tabs/additional-information.php`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce/tags/3.5.5/templates/single-product/tabs/additional-information.php).

So if you want to merge the two tabs, you can copy the "relevant" contents from the template file, like so:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'exetera_custom_product_tabs', 98 );
function exetera_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    // Custom description callback.
    $tabs['description']['callback'] = function() {
        global $post, $product;


        // Display the content of the Description tab.
        the_content();


        // Display the heading and content of the Additional Information tab.

        echo '<h2>Additional Information</h2>';

        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_additional_information', $product );
    };

    // Remove the additional information tab.
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );

    return $tabs;
}
```

### Alternate Version

Here we simply call the default callbacks and for the "Description" tab, we disable the default heading text.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'exetera_custom_product_tabs', 98 );
function exetera_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    // Custom description callback.
    $tabs['description']['callback'] = function() {
        // Disable the "Description" heading.
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_description_heading', '__return_empty_string' );

        // Display the content of the Description tab.
        woocommerce_product_description_tab();

        // Enable the "Description" heading.
        remove_filter( 'woocommerce_product_description_heading', '__return_empty_string' );


        // Display the heading and content of the Additional Information tab.
        woocommerce_product_additional_information_tab();
    };

    // Remove the additional information tab.
    unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );

    return $tabs;
}
```